# getting data from two api using promise.all

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I would like to get data from two API. in the firest call (getDatafromGeonames) I want to get latitude and longitude then I want to pass them as parameters to the second call (getWaetherData) to get weather information then I want to store the result and pass to my endpoint

Here is my try:

```
const res1 =   getDatafromGeonames(geonameAPIURL,city,geonamesKey).then(res =>{
          getWaetherData(res.address.lat, res.address.lng)})
  Promise.all([res1]).then((res)=>{
    //do somthing 
    console.log(res);
  })
```

[a screenshot of the result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dbUM.png)

I don't know why it is jumping to then and printing Undefined before it is executing getWaetherData? How can I get data from the first API then use these data to get weather info then do something with these data

thanks a lot :)

Comment: You cannot use promise.all since the two API calls should be one after the other

Answer (score 1):

`Promise.all` only works for Promises you can run in parallel, you have to run them in sequence instead:

```
getDataFromGeonames(geonameAPIURL, city, geonamesKey)
  .then((res) => getWeatherData(res.address.lat, res.address.lng))
  .then((res) => {
    // do something
    console.log(res);
    return res;
  });
```

Comment: if I run them in a sequence I get undefined when I log the res in the second then

Comment: If you want to access the `res` of the promise outside or in another `.then`, it has to be returned, but here nothing is being returned.

Answer (score 1):

`Promise.all(promises[])` method is meant to execute some logic when all `promises[]` has been executed. This would be helpful if you have 2 **independant** async calls and you want to do something after both of them has been executed.

By what you have described, seems that the second API call you have to do needs the result of the first API call, so the promise operator you should use is `.then()`.

```
const waetherData = getDatafromGeonames(geonameAPIURL,city,geonamesKey)
.then(res => getWaetherData(res.address.lat, res.address.lng))
```

or, in EMS6 style:

```
const getWaetherData = async (geonameAPIURL, city, geonamesKey) => {
      const geodata = await getDatafromGeonames(geonameAPIURL,city,geonamesKey);
      return await getWaetherData(geodata.address.lat, geodata.address.lng)
}
```

I have put this last code into a method because if you want to use `await` operator you need to be in a `async` context.

Comment: the first one is working but I don't know how can I use the response from the second call :(  the second has given me an error because of using await